# Elements pushed down after enlargement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created something that enlarges divs when they are hovered on, using `onmouseover`. They shrink back to their normal size, using `onmouseout`. But, for some reason, the divs are pushed down and stay there. This causes one of the divs to start glitching. How can I stop the divs from being pushed down, but still have the divs being enlarged and becoming smaller?
**UPDATE**
It has happened again when I put it with the rest of my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/pc65ve7b/

Can someone help me please?

```js
function enlarge(a, b, c, d) {
   a.style.height = "375px";
   b.style.height = "0px";
   c.style.height = "0px";
   d.style.height = "0px";
 };

 function shrink(a, b, c, d) {
   a.style.height = "125px";
   b.style.height = "125px";
   c.style.height = "125px";
   d.style.height = "125px";
 };
```

```css
.thing {
  height: 125px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
.aside {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside">
  <div id="c1"></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: blue;" id="c2" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c3'), document.getElementById('c4'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c3'), document.getElementById('c4'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: orange;" id="c3" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c4'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c4'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: pink" id="c4" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c3'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c3'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need JavaScript for this? Can't you just use CSS?

Comment: does this solves your problem https://jsfiddle.net/0vmr2c90/

Comment: No as it enlarges the aside element

Comment: I don't know if your elements are going to always be fixed height etc but with pure css you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/z4jn0a7v/

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why it's happening, but I can give you two fixes for it:

1. Use classes and toggle them, rather than manipulating `style` directly:

```js
function enlarge(a, b, c, d) {
  a.classList.add("enlarge");
  b.classList.add("make-room");
  c.classList.add("make-room");
  d.classList.add("make-room");
  }

function shrink(a, b, c, d) {
  a.classList.remove("enlarge");
  b.classList.remove("make-room");
  c.classList.remove("make-room");
  d.classList.remove("make-room");
}
```

```css
.thing {
  height: 125px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
.aside {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
.enlarge {
  height: 375px;
}
.make-room {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside">
  <div id="c1"></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: blue;" id="c2" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c3'), document.getElementById('c4'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c3'), document.getElementById('c4'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: orange;" id="c3" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c4'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c4'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: pink" id="c4" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c3'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c3'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
</aside>
```

2. Set `height` to `""` rather than a specific value:

```js
function enlarge(a, b, c, d) {
  a.style.height = "375px";
  b.style.height = "0px";
  c.style.height = "0px";
  d.style.height = "0px";
  }

function shrink(a, b, c, d) {
  a.style.height = "";
  b.style.height = "";
  c.style.height = "";
  d.style.height = "";
}
```

```css
.thing {
  height: 125px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
.aside {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside">
  <div id="c1"></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: blue;" id="c2" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c3'), document.getElementById('c4'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c3'), document.getElementById('c4'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: orange;" id="c3" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c4'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c4'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
  <div class="thing" style="background-color: pink" id="c4" onmouseover="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c3'))" onmouseout="shrink(this, document.getElementById('c1'), document.getElementById('c2'), document.getElementById('c3'))"><h1>hello</h1></div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you have set `b.style.height = "125px";` which is giving `<div id="c1"></div>` height of `125px`.

So just change your `shrink` function like this :

```
function shrink(a, b, c, d) {
  a.style.height = "125px";
  b.style.height = "0px";
  c.style.height = "125px";
  d.style.height = "125px";
};
```

This should work.